# Symbol not found Error in Unity3d - IOS Buid in Xcode

Tags: unity, ios

I new to IOS build , when  i try to build following error showing

I using Unity 5.2.1f1  and Xcode 7.0.1(7A1001)  . Previous   unity version was 5.0.1  , in that version , same error was found thats why  i updated unity , even though same error is existing

When i taking build Xcode showing  "Buid Succeeded" , when running on simulator , following error is showing .

Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/UserName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dzxhzbvzarcxwncwpymwfynqdipi/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/GameName.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

_**dyld: Symbol not found: _assignIdentifiersAndCallbackGameObject
  Referenced from: /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/400B12B2-B711-453C-B0E3-7DDF12A770F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E62986EE-618C-4530-B5F8-A09D43162DBD/GameName.app/GameName
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/UserName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/400B12B2-B711-453C-B0E3-7DDF12A770F0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E62986EE-618C-4530-B5F8-A09D43162DBD/GameName.app/GameName
(lldb)**

please help me , how to solve this problem